# Does 'static in generic type definition refer to the lifetime of the type itself or the lifetime of the params?

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime, rust-tokio

I wrote the following code but I don't fully understand why I have to use `'static` lifetimes.

```
use tokio::sync::watch::Receiver;


pub async fn combine_streams<T, F>(
    mut streams: Vec<Receiver<Option<T>>>,
    combiner: F,
) -> Receiver<Option<T>>
    where
        // I think "static" here refers to the lifetime of the type and not instances of it
        T: Clone + Send + Sync + Debug + 'static,
        F: Fn(Vec<Option<T>>) -> Option<T> + Send + Sync + 'static,
{
    let (tx, rx) = watch::channel(None);
    info!("Waiting for initial values...");
    while streams.iter_mut().any(|mut stream| stream.borrow_and_update().is_none()) {}

    let mut current_values = streams
        .iter()
        .map(|stream| stream.borrow().clone())
        .collect::<Vec<Option<T>>>();
    info!("Received initial values: {:?}", current_values);
    let combined_value = combiner(current_values.clone());
    tx.send(combined_value).expect("Couldn't send output over channel");

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            // wait for any stream to change
            let any_change =
                streams
                .iter_mut()
                    .map(|stream| stream.changed().boxed())
                    .collect::<Vec<BoxFuture<_>>>();

            let (_, index, _) = select_all(any_change).await;

            current_values[index] = streams[index].borrow().clone();

            let new_value = combiner(current_values.clone());
            tx.send(new_value).expect("Couldn't send output over channel");
        }
    });

    rx
}
```

I don't want to pass in objects that live forever. They are meant to be read from the channel and discarded.

- Why does either parameter need to be static?
- What is the meaning of `'static` here? does it refer to the lifetime of the type itself (as in, the concrete type for T or F, that will be used when calling)? Or does it refer to the lifetime of the particular instances passed in?

Comment: There no such thing as "lifetime of a type". Only values have lifetimes.

Comment: @PitaJ right, I was trying to think of a reason because I don't understand why my values have to have a static lifetime

Comment: `'static` there essentially means that `T` cannot be a reference to anything temporary. Owned values like `u32` or `String` are `'static`.

Comment: What if it's a struct made up of u32 and String fields?

Comment: As long as it doesn't have references, it should be fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "references"? You mean e.g. `a: &str`? That's not true tho, you can have a reference with a static lifetime, no?

Comment: Yes, static references are fine. I just meant that `struct Foo<'a>(&'a str)` would generally not be allowed (only be allowed for `Foo<'static>`).

Comment: This is [common lifetime misconception #2](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program): `'static` does _not_ mean that the value lives for the entire program, it only means that the objects will live for as long as the receiver needs them.

Comment: @Jmb this was exactly what I was confused about.. it "sounds" like it means it lives for as long as the program runs, but then I noticed that is not actually true. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @Jmb just wanted to say that you're the only one who actually answered my question, and it's thanks to this really good page you sent me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lifetime bound on a generic means that the generic type must be valid for *at most* that lifetime - but it may be dropped or disused before that lifetime elapses.

For `T: 'static` that means that `T` must be *able* to last as long as `'static` (i.e. until the death of the program), but that doesn't mean it necessarily will.

`tokio::spawn` requires that the future passed to it, and all the data it contains, be able to last until the program is terminated, since, unless you call `join` on its return value, the task may loop forever and never actually terminate. If it were possible for the task to be passed a temporary reference, it would mean it could access that reference after the value it was pointing to had been dropped.

Comment: This is what I've been [reading](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program), but can you give me an example of a type that would not satisfy `T: 'static`?

Comment: @SpaceMonkey Any type with a lifetime generic, i.e. `struct Foo<'a>`, where that lifetime doesn't happen to be `'static`.

Answer (score 0):

The `'a` bound on a type is a bound on the lifetime of any reference embedded in a value of the type.

That is, `T: 'a` means that any value of `T` must NOT embed references with a lifetime strictly shorter than `'a`.

This means that the only fields, recursively, allowed are:

- Fields that do not embed a reference, at all, such as owned values: u32, `String`, `Vec`, ...
- Fields that embed only references with a lifetime greater than or equal to `'a`, such as for any `'b: 'a`: `&'b X`, `Cow<'b, X>`, ...

This, in turn, guarantee that any value of `T` can be used safely for as long as `'a` has not ended.

Comment: Why do params of type T need to have a static lifetime though? It seems like "static" does not mean instances of T will not be deallocated, so I'm clearly misunderstanding what it means to have a static lifetime. It doesn't seem to mean "live for as long as the program is running". Do you see my confusion?

Comment: I see the comment by @Jmb now